# How to change size of ListView rows

Tags: android, listview

I have 2 ways of displaying ListView data.  I have a class for each type of row.  I do not create the rows in an xml layout.  (Each row is derived from View and does custom drawing).

When I switch from 1 type of row to another how do I get the ListView to layout properly with the correct row heights, and refresh?

Is View.forceLayout() on the right track?

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you use adapter to fill your ListView?
In my code i have some adapter and when i have to change row type i set adapter to null and then to new adapter type.

Comment: Yes, I extend BaseAdapter.  I was using a boolean to get my adapter to return 1 or the other view type.  I will try 2 seperate adapers.